# How to get the root path of the project

Tags: go, path

I run the following code `workingDir, _ := os.Getwd()` 
in `server.go` file which is under the root project and get the root path,
Now I need to move the `server.go` file to the following structure

```
myapp
  src
   server.go
```

and I want to ge the path of `go/src/myapp` 
currently after I move the `server.go` under `myapp->src>server.go` I got path of `go/src/myapp/src/server.go` and I want to get the previews  path ,

How should I do it in go automatically? or should I put `../` explicit in get path ?

Comment: When you run a Go program, there is no "project". You're just running a compiled binary; it has no concept of where it's source code might be (or even if it exists on the machine where it's running), nor should it.

Comment: @Adrian - thanks the problem is that I need to read json file from the root project, the problem that it working very strange ,when I run the program in goland it provide path like 'go/src/myapp/` and when I run it in vsCode I got this path `go/src/myapp/src/server.go` im running it on the exact same project so I want to find some generic solution, how would you do it ?

Comment: I'd make the path configurable by config file, command line flag, and/or environment variable.

Comment: @Adrian - can you please provide some example ? like for my project root path ? thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`os.Getwd()` does not return your source file path. It returns program current working directory (Usually the directory that you executed your program).

Example:

Assume I have a main.go in `/Users/Arman/go/src/github.com/rmaan/project/main.go` that just outputs `os.Getwd()`

```
$ cd /Users/Arman/go/src/github.com/rmaan/project/
$ go run main.go
/Users/Arman/go/src/github.com/rmaan/project <nil>
```

If I change to other directory and execute there, result will change.

```
$ cd /Users/Arman/
$ go run ./go/src/github.com/rmaan/project/main.go
/Users/Arman <nil>
```

---

IMO you should explicitly pass the path you want to your program instead of trying to infer it from context (As it may change specially in production environment). Here is an example with `flag` package.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "flag"
)


func main() {
    var myPath string
    flag.StringVar(&myPath, "my-path", "/", "Provide project path as an absolute path")
    flag.Parse()

    fmt.Printf("provided path was %s\n", myPath)
}
```

then execute your program as follows:

```
$ cd /Users/Arman/go/src/github.com/rmaan/project/
$ go run main.go  --my-path /Users/Arman/go/src/github.com/rmaan/project/
provided path was /Users/Arman/go/src/github.com/rmaan/project/
$ # or more easily
$ go run main.go  --my-path `pwd`
provided path was /Users/Arman/go/src/github.com/rmaan/project/
```

Comment: Ok but how should I resolve it to the parent project in case im in the structure of `myapp/src/server.go` ?

Comment: My point is your project structure is irrelevant. Usually paths are passed to program explicitly via flags (https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) or config files.

Comment: Ok thanks, so how should I update it via flag and how should I go up two levels ?

Comment: @Ninawatcher Updated my post to include an example.

Comment: Thanks 1+ , you put it on main and the path is `/` but how it should be in case you are not in the main and you are using the path as in my question `myapp/src/server.go` to provide it in any file structure whether if I put it on  `myapp/src/server.go` or for example `myapp/src/util/server.go` can you provide example to this ?

Comment: Im not sure how you example help here since I want to run the program without provide any path...

Comment: @Ninawatcher Don't think there is a way to get a source file path in a compiled programming language! There is no source file when program is running. You could use `filepath.Abs(os.Args[0])` to get location of current running program and use `filepath.Dir` to get its parent directory.

Answer (score 6):

If your project is a git repository you can also use the `git rev-parse` command with the `--show-toplevel`:

```golang
cmdOut, err := exec.Command("git", "rev-parse", "--show-toplevel").Output()
if err != nil {
    assert.Fail(t, fmt.Sprintf(`Error on getting the go-kit base path: %s - %s`, err.Error(), string(cmdOut)))
    return
}

fmt.Println(strings.TrimSpace(string(cmdOut)))
```

It'll print out the git project home path wherever in the sub path you are